# Hello World in C++ Using a Conda Build Environment

Tags: c++, anaconda, conda

I'm setting up a shared `conda` build environment to help me collaborate with a colleague.

I'm fairly new to conda and have only used it for python programming before. But now I'd like to use it for `c++` projects too.

I've run `conda install -c gcc` which has installed `gcc` and `g++`. I can verify this with the output of `g++ --version`.

```
>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

When I do this outside my conda environment I get this:

```
>g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

So I know that the install has worked.

I have this hello world code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

And try compiling it like this:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
```

But I get this error message:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
In file included from /Users/me/anaconda/envs/VolumeEstimation/gcc/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40:0,
                 from /Users/me/anaconda/envs/VolumeEstimation/gcc/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                 from /Users/me/anaconda/envs/VolumeEstimation/gcc/include/c++/ios:38,
                 from /Users/me/anaconda/envs/VolumeEstimation/gcc/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from /Users/me/anaconda/envs/VolumeEstimation/gcc/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/Users/me/anaconda/envs/VolumeEstimation/gcc/include/c++/cwchar:44:19: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wchar.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

How can I best resolve this?

Comment: Try looking for wchar.h in your `usr/include` , is it there?

Comment: No, there's `cwchar` instead, how can I fix this in my conda environment?

Comment: try to perform a file search, and include that new path